# A question on vector components with respect to an embedding on a manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-spaces, smooth-manifolds

I've been working my way through Nakahara's book "*Geometry, topology and physics*" and I'm currently reading through chapter 7 (on Riemannian geometry). In the 2nd section of the chapter he gives a heuristic introduction to parallel transport and it is the example that he gives that I'm struggling with a bit. The bit I'm unsure about is as follows:

*Consider the two-dimensional Euclidean space $(\mathbb{R},\delta)$ and take the polar coordinates $(r,\phi)$. If $(r,\phi)\mapsto (r\cos (\phi),r\sin (\phi))$ is regarded as an embedding, we find the induced metric, $$g=dr\otimes dr +r^{2}d\phi\otimes d\phi.$$ Now, let $\mathbf{V}=V^{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}+V^{\phi}\frac{\partial}{\partial\phi}$ be a vector defined at $(r,\phi)$. We have then, that it's components are $$V^{r}=V\cos (\theta)\qquad\text{and}\qquad V^{\phi}=\frac{V}{r}\sin (\theta)$$ where $V=\sqrt{g(\mathbf{V},\mathbf{V})}$ and $\theta$ is the angle between $\mathbf{V}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial r}$.*

I get that these are projections of the vector onto the basis vectors $\lbrace\frac{\partial}{\partial r}, \frac{\partial}{\partial \phi}\rbrace$, but I can't figure out how he gets the expressions for the components?

(apologies, I may be just having a very stupid moment, my mind has gone a bit blank on this one).